# how to implement a listener in android

Tags: android, callback, listener

I'm writing an Android app to call some server api functions, like sign in. The problem is that I don't want to do in the blocking way. I'd like to do the sign in in background and have a listener(it's no a click listener) to tell me when the sign in is complete. I'm new to android. I'm not asking to have a working code. if anyone can give some suggestions or tutorial link, that will be much helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: you could use a `service` ,`asynctask` or a `thread`.

Comment: @Raghunandan, These three things are used for do sign in in background. But how do I implement the listener to tell when the sign in is ready.

Comment: you can use a handler and use a boolean to report back the status.

Comment: @Raghunandan, for my task--calling a rest api in background, which one (service, asynctask and thread) do think is better? what's the difference of them?

Comment: you can use volley as suggested by Karakuri. Its a library for fast networking.

Answer (score 1):

Do whatever you want to do like calling functions in the `onCreate()` **method**, because whenever the app is made to run,  it will be the first to execute..

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own threading, or you can use something provided by Android. Off the top of my head, `AsyncTask` and `IntentService` both do work on a background thread.

I would take a look at the Volley library for Android. They had a session about it at Google I/O this year ([video link](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138)). [This blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library) explains how to get the library and start using it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in multiple ways.

1. Using `AsyncTask` or `Thread`
2. Using `IntentService` or `Service`

I would suggest you to look at [Vogella Training](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) to learn about Background Processing
Also [Android API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) might help you out in learning about Services.

If you are doing some long running operation I think option 2 is the ideal, if not simply do your task with option 1.

> Hope this helps!!!!!!!